# Error creating control in asp.net while creating a menu in master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

when working on a master page i tried to create a menu in my page but it throws me an error called

> Error creating control-cpl1
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions,
>   version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies.This system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Is DOTNET v3.5 installed on the machine?

Comment: Have you checked the references folder to see if the above assembly exists?

Comment: Is your project is 2.0 and you are trying to use 3.5 extensions, like Ajax Control Toolkit?

Comment: I don't use ajax control its just a simple master page content place holder is not working

Comment: I added the reference but it doesn't works

Comment: I am using .net 3.5 framework

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to the specified assembly and your're done